# What causes un-expected delay in method using setTimeout?

Tags: javascript

There is a 43 msec delay between middle and complete which should only be 1msec as this is what a timeout has beet set to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 43ms delay is probably time the browser is spending downloading and parsing jQuery. JavaScript is single threaded in most (all?) browsers, and I think it's common for browsers to pause script execution while new scripts are being downloaded.

As for functions not working, have you tried other jQuery functions? It's suspicious to me that the only functions that aren't working for you are the ones you're redefining.